# Issues with Laravel 5.4 reset password function

Tags: xampp, laravel-5.4

I am getting the following error when i reset password in laravel 5.4

Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError s7sm7398940pgb.53 - gsmtp
"

I have correctly entered the username and password aswell as tls and smtp.gmail.com in my env. file.My mail.php file also has the correct credentials.
As for the gmail side of things:My security settings have been set to allow this to work by changing my security settings:Switching on Access for less secure apps.

And my local server,xampp has been sending emails back and forth between all the content management systems ive ever worked on for the past 2 years.I am using laravel 5.4 for the first time.

Heres my .env file

```
APP_NAME=MyApp
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:---------=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mypwd

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=myemailpwd
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=

PAYPAL_MODE=
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID=
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_SECRET=
PAYPAL_LIVE_CLIENT_ID=
PAYPAL_LIVE_SECRET=
```

And heres my mail.php

```
    <?php
return [ 
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', '587'),

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myemail@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'myname'),
    ],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('myemail@gmail.com'),

    'password' => env('myemailpwd'),

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: Do you run laravel with `php artisan serve`? If so, after changing your .env, restart the server.

Comment: Already did that...i also cleared the cache before artisan serve:(php artisan cache:clear and php artisan config:cache),but still getting the error.

Comment: Perhaps add your .env config (without username and pw)? Basically for email to work, you only have to make changes to .env, nothing else. (and in gmail's case you have to allow this, but you already did that.)

Comment: both .env and config/mail.php have to have the same configurations.And my smtp requires authorization,otherwise it wont work at all...that is with regards to your solution of not adding username and pwd in .env config

Comment: I meant posting your code here, and removing your credentials before posting it here. It wouldn't be the first time someone made a typo somewhere. And right now you are the only one who knows what was changed in the config files and .env, all I see is someone who probably made a typo :)

Comment: ok...will do...

Comment: Check the changes in the question..ive added the .env and mail.php file

Comment: I posted the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Change this in your `config/mail.php`

```
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', 'fallback email'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', 'fallback password'),
```

The first param is used for the key as it is defined in your .env, the second one is the default value in case the `env('KEY')` returns null.

The problem is right now it searches for the key `'myemail@gmail.com'` in your .env file, which does not exist, the key name is `'MAIL_USERNAME'`.

Comment: thanks bro.I edited the config/mail.php but i am still getting an error response on password reset::Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError 75sm21180112pfk.113 - gsmtp
"

Comment: Open up tinker by typing: `php artisan tinker` and type: `config('mail');`. Are those values correct?

Comment: How about the 3 options in this post: https://learninglaravel.net/learn-to-send-emails-using-gmail-and-sendgrid-in-laravel-5